# Serialize/Deserialize Wot Json API

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have the following Json from : https://www.mywot.com/wiki/API

```
{
    "google.com": {
        "target": "google.com",
        "0": [94, 73],
        "1": [94, 73],
        "2": [94, 73],
        "4": [93, 67],
        "categories": {
            "501": 99,
            "301": 48,
            "304": 5
        }
    },
    "yahoo.com": {
        "target": "yahoo.com",
        "0": [94, 75],
        "1": [94, 75],
        "2": [94, 75],
        "4": [93, 69],
        "categories": {
            "501": 99,
            "301": 16,
            "304": 11
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use C# MVC Model + Json.net to serialize and deserialize the Json.
I tried with the following model, but i have 2 problems:

1. The website name is a variable (google.com, yahoo.com)
2. The categories keys are numbers (MVC models don't allow number as key).

---

```
public class Categories
{
    public int 401 { get; set; }
    public int 501 { get; set; }
}

public class Website 
{
    public string target { get; set; }
    public List<int> 0 { get; set; }
    public List<int> 1 { get; set; }
    public List<int> 2 { get; set; }
    public List<int> 4 { get; set; }
    public Categories categories { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Website domain_name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your json is very dirty. And you can't set name for variable like 0,1,2,3.
In this case you need use   `[JsonProperty("HERE_IS_PROPERTY_NAME")]` attribute.

Below code that work and parse your json.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"google.com\":{\"target\":\"google.com\",\"0\":[94,73],\"1\":[94,73],\"2\":[94,73],\"4\":[93,67],\"categories\":{\"501\":99,\"301\":48,\"304\":5}},\"yahoo.com\":{\"target\":\"yahoo.com\",\"0\":[94,75],\"1\":[94,75],\"2\":[94,75],\"4\":[93,69],\"categories\":{\"501\":99,\"301\":16,\"304\":11}}}";

            Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
            List<Website> sites = new List<Website>();
            foreach (var item in dictionary_data)
            {
                string data = Convert.ToString(item.Value);
                data = data.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty); ;
                Website site = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Website>(data);
                sites.Add(site);
            }
        }
    }


    public class Categories
    {
        [JsonProperty("401")]
        public int a { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("501")]
        public int b { get; set; }
    }
    public class Website
    {
        public string target { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("0")]
        public List<int> FirstList { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public List<int> SecondList { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("2")]
        public List<int> ThirdList { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("4")]
        public List<int> FourList { get; set; }
        public Categories categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Website domain_name { get; set; }
    }
```